# Download multiple file (>1000) NSURlConnection cause crash

Tags: ios, download, nsurlconnection

In my app I have to download multiple files (more than 1000 files) at a time from a server.
I created operation queues to download them. But I have to start urlconnection on main thread so that the delegate methods can be called. Everything's working fine but after 600 files app goes crash without any log.

Here are the steps I am using :

1. Create an operation of nsurlconnection.
2. Add operation to a queue.
3. Start operation on main thread. ( I also tried `[connection scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];` but dint work.)

But after more that 500 files app crashes every time.
Any help is welcome.

Comment: How many are you running concurrently? What are you doing with the files once you download them? How big are they?

Comment: I am running 4 files currently. after downloading I am saving them to doc directory. Some of them are more than 3o Mb but most of them are around 10 to 20 Mb

Comment: And as you save you're writing each block of data out to the file (using a file handle or something), or you're accumulating all of the data in memory and then writing it out to disk once complete?

Comment: When a file is downloaded I write it on the disk.

Comment: Have you find any solution for this because I am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Each time the connection receives data (notified to the delegate with `connection:didReceiveData:`) you should write that data out to disk immediately. This ensures that the minimum amount of data is held in memory at any one time. If you don't and you're downloading multiple large files at the same time you can easily cause a low memory situation which will cause the app to be terminated.

Comment: Thanks for the ans @wain. I tried this approach also. I appended data in didRecieveData and write data to disk but I got the same result. It still crashing after 500 files.:(